# Excel-VBA to return using LEFT of vlookup result

Tags: vba, excel

I have a program that is based on a simple lookup and it works and returns the correct value. I was wondering if there is a way to incorporate the =LEFT function to make it return the first two characters of the vlookup result.

```
    ub Store_Lookup_left_test()
Dim rw As Long, x As Range
Dim extwbk As Workbook, twb As Workbook

Set twb = ThisWorkbook
Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open("H:\****\****\Master Store Info.xlsm")
Set x = extwbk.Worksheets("Info Sheet").Range("A1:C999999")

With twb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For rw = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(rw, 10) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, x, 3, False)
    Next rw
End With
```

So by analogy to `=Left(vlookup(a1,A1:C1,3,0),2)`, can I do something similar like
`.cells(rw, 10) = application.left(application.vlookup(.cells(rw, 1).Value2, x, 3, False),2)` ?

At the moment the vlookup result is

> UK Optical, or Irish Optical

and I want it to be

> UK, Ir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you just need:

```
.cells(rw, 10) = Left(application.vlookup(.cells(rw, 1).Value2, x, 3, False),2)
```

this uses the built in [Left VBA function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y050k1wb(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Have just tried and it returned the "run-time error '13', Type Mismatch" for .Cells(rw, 10) = Left(Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, x, 3, False), 2) I've read the documentation, many thanks. Do I need to introduce another variable and declare it as String?

Comment: that probably means you are getting an empty cell result back from your lookup.

First I would change Set x = extwbk.Worksheets("Info Sheet").Range("A1:C999999")  - to use a range that dosn't have empty cells in it.

Comment: then assign application.vlookup(.cells(rw, 1).Value2, x, 3, False) to a variable and check if it is empty before doing a left on the result

Comment: @user8449681 I've edited my answer to include an error check, as this was causing your type mismatch error.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the [`Left`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/left-function) function directly in VBA, but you need to check what the `vlookup` returns, because if there was no match it will return an error which `Left` cannot use.

```
' Get vlookup result as variant so no error occurs if not string
Dim lookupresult As Variant
lookupresult = Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, x, 3, False)
' Check if vlookup returned an error (no match found)
If IsError(lookupresult) Then
    MsgBox "Error with vlookup, no match found"
Else
    ' Get Left of string, up to 2 characters.
    .Cells(rw, 10) = Left(lookupresult, 2)
End If
```

Comment: If you add a check of lookupresult for empty then this is what you want - unless there is some other reason for the tpe mismarch?

Comment: Using Min is redundant (`Left(lookupresult,2)` will give correct result for empty strings). `Type Mismatch` will be raised in previous line when VLOOKUP doesn't find anything and return `Variant/Error`.

Comment: You're right @BrakNicku, I've corrected my answer which now deals with the actual problem